# Need to Index a Magento 1.9 table with Algolia search

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-ce, algolia

I've got a magento extension that is a custom blog ( Amasty ) .  It doesn't use attributes of any kind to index the posts , but it's own custom table - blog_posts.

I'm not sure what is the best angel to take with this.  If I could create an index of attributes that indexed the table? ( doesn't sound like a good idea )

I found a few posts about customising the extension

https://community.algolia.com/magento/doc/m1/customize-extension/
https://community.algolia.com/magento/doc/m1/indexing/

But I don't think they touch on what I need.

Thanks or your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I achieved what you're trying to gain via a custom module - it will require you to set up a collection of your blog table, or use the Amasty custom blog collection if you want. (My code was written for Algolia search 1.5.5 on Magento 1.9.2.4CE)

```
  public function indexProducts() {

      if (class_exists('AlgoliaSearch\Client', false) == false)
      {
          require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/AlgoliaSearch/Version.php';
          require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/AlgoliaSearch/AlgoliaException.php';
          require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/AlgoliaSearch/ClientContext.php';
          require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/AlgoliaSearch/Client.php';
          require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/AlgoliaSearch/Index.php';
          require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/AlgoliaSearch/PlacesIndex.php';
          require_once Mage::getBaseDir('lib').'/AlgoliaSearch/IndexBrowser.php';
      }

      $client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_ADMIN_API_KEY');

      // YOUR COLLECTION HERE OF BLOG POSTS...
      $collection = $this->getCollection();

      $results = array();
      $i = 0;

      foreach ($collection as $post) {

        $results[$i]['objectID'] = $post->getId();
        $results[$i]['title'] = $post->getTitle();
        $results[$i]['content'] = $post->getContent();

       $i++;

      }

      // index in algolia you want to add to
      $index = $client->initIndex('blog_index');
      $batch = $results;
      //print_R($batch);
      $index->addObjects($batch);

    }
```